# Visual studio extension - Creating unit test for method the suppose to run on the UI thread

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

How can I create unit tests for a method that should run on UI Thread? For example:
The method to test:

```
    public void MenuItemBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

        // Do something
    }
```

The test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnitTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Create Target

        // Act
        target.MenuItemBeforeQueryStatus(null, EventArgs.Empty);

        // Assert
    }
```

The exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: MenuItemBeforeQueryStatus must be called on the UI thread. For UWP projects, if you are using UI objects in test consider using [UITestMethod] attribute instead of [TestMethod] to execute test in UI thread.
```

Does `UITestMethod` relevant in my case? I don't use UWP, I develop an extension for visual studio.

How can I create a test for it?

Comment: What do you have inside `MenuItemBeforeQueryStatus` method? Is there any calls to `Dispatcher` or `Dispatcher` timer? Running tests on `STA` thread might be helpful

Comment: *Does UITestMethod relevant in my case?* Did you tried to use it?  *How can I create a test for it?* do not test `MenuItemBeforeQueryStatus` but rather `// Do something`